# Passing arry in Json request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

I am having problems in receiving my Json request where I send an array in one of my data.

I am converting my array using Json.stringify() as

```
for (var chartSeries = 0; chartSeries < chartObj.series.length; chartSeries++) {

    var point = chartObj.series[chartSeries].data;
    currentTime = point[point.length - 1].currentTime;
    var tagName = point[point.length - 1].tagName;
    lastUpdate[chartSeries] = [{
        'lastUpdatedTime': currentTime
    }, {
        'TagName': tagName
    }];

}
var updatedTime = JSON.stringify(lastUpdate);
```

and I pass it on my data as

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/ProxyPage.aspx/GetLatestPIDashboardChartData",
  data: "{\"pageChartIdString\":\"" + $("#<%= lblChartGUID.ClientID %>").val() + "\"" +
                    ",\"updatedTime \":\"" + currentTime + "}",
```

Now on my aspx page,

```
public static JsonMikonAjaxResponse GetLatestPIDashboardChartData(string pageChartIdString, String[,] lastUpdateArray) {
}
```

How do I need to receive it on my Response Function say `GetLatestPIDashboardChartData()`? Is String[,] lastUpdateArray causing problems? How do I declare it then?

Comment: You don't need to build the JSON manually. You can pass a Javascript object directly as your `data`.

Comment: You shouldn't definitely use `JSON.stringify` and not build the JSON yourself.

Comment: then how can i pass my array in the request???? I need a way to pass my array in my request and to receive it on my Response function as well.  Please help

Comment: `var arr=[...]; $.ajax({data:arr,...});`